# Scrollable html table with fixed first row and first column, along with angular material controls within the cells of table

Tags: html, css, angular-material-7

I want to achieve the below result without using jquery:

1. The table for which data should be scrollable for both axis.
2. The first column (table header) and first row of the table should be a fixed and with auto adjustable width for the column as per the data entered, similar to google spreadsheet

[image: valid XHTML]

Above image shows what I have tried, the  element containing the table has overflow-x: auto for the horizontal scroll and the  element has style="display:block;height:400px;overflow-y:auto" for the vertical scroll for fixed table header. Also some  elements contain mat-elements

Following is the html code for above image:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Textbox_1</th>
                    <th>Textbox_1</th>
                    <th>Multichoice</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="display:block;height:400px;overflow-y:auto">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><div>John</div></td>
                    <td><div>Ron</div></td>
                    <td><div><mat-select><mat-option>One</mat-option>
                                         <mat-option>Two</mat-option>
                             </mat-select>
                        </div>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Expected Result:

[image: valid XHTML]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible with CSS only. You might need support of JavaScript/JQuery. Check out this light weight plugin. It will help you for sure.

https://github.com/nitsugario/jQuery-Freeze-Table-Column-and-Rows